# Which data is sent via form?

Tags: html, forms, post, checkbox, get

Given an HTML form, such as a text field and two checkboxes, which data is provided through the form? For each element, is your data sent by id or name identifier or can it vary depending on the types of form elements?
In the specific case of two checkboxes, is the content of each one sent by its own ID or is it transmitted an array with the data of both by another identifier?

Comment: Fields are sent by name, and the same thing goes for the checkbox, if they have the same name and they are both checked, the submitted data will be : `name=value1&name=value2`. [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form data is sent in an array via the `name` of each element.

So if you have a `checkbox`, the **value** of that checkbox will be the data sent.  IE:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Toyota"> I have a car<br />
```

The array in, say, `php` can be seen with `print-R($_POST);`.